# Intellij: Gradle syn failed

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm new to Andriod app development. I installed android Intellij, but while creating a project, I'm getting an error saying-

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: error in opening zip file
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

I replaced my gradle file with the new file but still facing the same issue.

It's giving me the error that the gradle file can not be zipped.

Comment: Oh gosh, show your log

Comment: how can we figure out error with just these two lines?

Comment: The log file is of 1 mb which I'm unable to upload :( @Vyacheslav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried every possible solution but didn't work. At last, removed Android Studio completely and begin fresh download and installation. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

Check: Offline work

And then:

File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart.